# How to bring the user back from Wifi Settings screen opened via an intent: Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-wifi

I have to send the user to the Wifi settings screen to select a wifi and then bring him back after he does is selection. 
Now taking him to the Wifi Settings page is fine, I can do that via an intent but then it never comes back to the app.

How to i do that? I could only find answers which take him to the Wifi Screen but none of get them back.

Thanks and regards, 
Sunny

Comment: If you open the wifi settings screen with an intent that adds it to your current task stack, then if the user presses the back button, or the up button on the action bar, it will take them back to your activity.

Comment: You need to post your code, if you start an activity, then when the user hits back, it should bring the user back to your app. If you app is closing it may be because you're calling `finish()` or because there is a setting in your `manifest` that may be terminating your app.

Comment: You can't force user to come back to your activity, they may just traverse through the other menus and or go to the home. What you can do, if really want, create your own activity/dialog to perform all the wi-fi activities.

Comment: no my app is not closing the app. The point is that is there no way to get him back without him pressing the back button, like in case of picking a photo

Comment: @jitainsharma but that would that i would have to handle the changing wifi settings in the app itself when the user selects a particular wifi. but i want to user the system defaults

Comment: If it's easy to call than on the other hand it has some cons as well.

Comment: In addiction to what you have already done, you can monitor the connectivity changes and bring your activity back to foreground. Instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)